# exposing RPC/ws publicaly

Tags: rpc

I want to expose an RPC/WS endpoints publicly. What mesures should I take into consideration?
Should I just expose RPC/WS using substrate options  --unsafe-rpc-external --unsafe-ws-external?

But as I understand  --unsafe-rpc-external --unsafe-ws-external are not safe so how to expose ws and rpc safely?

Answer (score 0):

Use `--rpc-external`(http) or `--ws-external`(ws).

`--unsafe-x-external` is designed for the validator/collator node. It is not recommended to expose the endpoints of an authority node. If you want to do that anyway, use these two unsafe flags.

---

Why unsafe?

For example:

- `author_insertKeys` call will generate session keys files in your disk
- `state_getStoragePaged` is a recursive query call, which will cost lots of performance(CPU/MEM)

Tips: `--rpc-method auto/unsafe` provides more controlling options at a different level.